# Does AWS CLI bring data across local network when doing `aws s3 mv` between two S3 locations?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

When moving data between two S3 locations using the AWS CLI, for example:

`aws s3 mv s3://bucket/prefix s3://bucket/other-prefix`

Is the data downloaded to your local computer and then re-uploaded? Or does it stay in the data center? Is it different for `cp` vs `mv`, or if moving data between buckets in different regions/azs?

Comment: The way to work this out is to put a 1GB file into S3 and move it, watching your network usage while it executes. Once you do that please answer your question below.

Comment: It seems the answer to such a basic question would be easy to find in AWS documentation, but in my searching I have not found it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did some testing into s3 as mentioned by @tim and after monitoring network usage, I determined that the answer is no, data is not moved across your local network